# Using ToString on a DateTime object

Tags: c#, datetime, overloading, object-to-string

In my database the date is stored like datetime but when I want to perform a search/filtering I want it to be based only on the date ignoring the exact time. I spend a lot of time figuring out how to do it and finally I got a working solution on my own :

```
string val = rule.Data;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
{
switch (rule.Field)
                    {
                        case "Date": {
                        DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
                                val,
                                "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                        var pYear = parsedDate.Year;
                        var pMonth = parsedDate.Month;
                        var pDay = parsedDate.Day;

rows = rows.Where(o => o.Date >= parsedDate && o.Date <= new DateTime(pYear, pMonth, pDay, 12, 59, 40)); break;
                        }
                    }
```

}

This is working Ok. It needs a little change but I think I can use the code above. However today a college of mine pass me a solution which is from a previous project being developed here, and this solution is a lot shorter and I would prefer to use it if possble. It looks like this:

```
        string val = rule.Data;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
        {
            switch (rule.Field)
            {
            case "Date": { rows = rows.Where(o => o.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") == val); break; }
            }
        }
```

The code doesn't break when I try this but it's not filtering data too. I always get empty result. I guess that `o.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` is where the problem lies. I don't know is it ok to use `ToString()` like this for DateTime object. In the example I'm using `ToString()` also get a format type like the one I'm providing here - `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` - but in my case `ToString()` is not overloaded anywhere. Is this a standard way to manipulate DateTime objects or I just can't find the place where `ToStrin()` is predefined. And finally, can you provide me with a working example based on the code above.

Comment: did you try to debug if `o.Date.ToString(` is really the problem? `Date.ToString` doesn't need an overload to correctly format a `Date` to `string` object.

Comment: I used `DateTime submitDate = DateTime.Now.Date;` to get todays date in the format you want. Then I enter it into a table like: `mes.SubmitDate = submitDate;` - worked for me.

Comment: Well, I've read some articles. It seems like it should work, my `val` variable has value `"03/06/2013"` and when I give the format type for `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` I think that I should get results if something math and there are dates that match, but I don't get the result. And I don't see a lot of room for mistakes if it's not the format I use then what could it be?

Comment: ToString() should work. At least I use the following code: date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") and it's working fine.

Comment: Yeah I just hard coded a few test cases - `ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == "2013-06-03"` is returning the expected results when `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") == "03/06/2013"` is returning empty result, so could it be that `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` is not a valid format for some reason?

Comment: Well I think that the backslash is causing the problem here, the same format used with backslashes -`ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` but replacing the `\` with dots `.` like .ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") == 03.06.2013` and again I get the correct result.

Comment: Indeed, if the code works in another project it must be the input date format that's screwy, btw  String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt); // "9/3/2008 16:05:07" - english (en-US)
String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt); // "9.3.2008 16:05:07" - german (de-DE)

Comment: Is there some way to make this snippet more universal by adding something like `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` (I'm not sure where) so the code will be working fine with this format no matter the cultural settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what culture o.Date is, Try:

```
    string val = rule.Data;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
    {
        switch (rule.Field)
        {
              case "Date":
              {
                rows = rows.Where(o => o.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == 
                                          DateTime.ParseExact(val,
                                          "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                break;
              }
        }
    }
```

Or you could set the culture of the current thread instead:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

**Edit**: It should work if you avoid using strings:

e.g.

```
DateTime maxDate = new DateTime(2020, 11, 17);

if (DateTime.Now.Date > maxDate)
{
   // this will just work regardless of setting culture
}
```

Comment: No, Setting the culture to the thread is not an option, but your answer seems like some mix between the two I've been looking at. Maybe I'll consider it, even though I liked the fact that in the second example Parsing is not used.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you need to compare dates then you can just get a Date component of a DateTime and compare it to your predefined value. This should be faster as there won't be a need to transform date to string every time as well. So you can first get your reference value like that `DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvarianCulture)`. You can just use a constructor of a DateTime to compose it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to use strings at all.  If it is a `datetime` (or similar) in the database, and a `DateTime` in your c# code, then there is never a good reason to use a string as an intermediate step.

Also, you should pay close attention to the `.Kind` property of your `DateTime` values.  And you should never be comparing local times against `DateTime.Now`.  If you do, you may introduce errors during daylight saving time transitions.  Instead, you should use UTC `DateTime` values, or use `DateTimeOffset` values instead.  [Read more here](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).